# Upload image from iphone to facebook without dialog

Tags: iphone

i want to send image from my iphone to facebook of my account without showing any dialog (in fbconnect there is dialog) . I want a simple way to just test whether it is uploaded in the facebook are not.

I tested with twitter api send message from my iphone and its work fine its few lines of code,

I pasted below

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml"]
                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 

                                 timeoutInterval: 60.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=%@", @"test message sends from iphone"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* error;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]);
```

Like wise i want to send text and photo to facebook account ? Is it possible ?

The fbconnect is more no of blocks and lines , can anyone help me ? a simple way to understand it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With the new OAuth Facebook API and the new facebook-ios-sdk I don't think you can do without the dialog. The whole point is that your app never sees and stores the user credentials. If you then close the app and the login dialog appears again a cookie (set/used by the UIWebView, AFAIK) logs you in without you needing to enter the credentials again.